# Call function from UIButton in UICellView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with custom cells. On cell I have a buttons, and a method in my `viewController` (which contains `UITableView`)

My button click realisation is inside my `myCustomCell` class.

And the question is - What is the simplest way to call `viewController` method from `myCustomCell`?

I thought about delegates and NSNotificationCenter. But maybe there is another way.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: delegation is the way to go - set up the delegate property of the cell inside the cellForRow-method

Comment: In 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' Method, `myCustomCell.someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`.

Comment: Delegation is overkill for this task, do what @Mahesh suggests

Comment: And what if I have collectionView inside cell, for example, and need to handle every cell in collectionView?

Comment: What do you want, a collection view or a tableview, 

well, you can set protocol, as I have answers, in both, 2. You can also do as Mahesh said, but I prefer protocols, as it gives you power, to call more methods, and more power, and clean architecture.

Comment: I don't see any reason for putting a collection view inside a table view cell. Just use a collection view then (you can have a variable number of items in each section).

Comment: collectionview inside cell? Can I see design, how you like, so we could suggest you better idea to make it in right way.

Comment: @Arthur regarding your edit. That could easily be done with only a collection view. The label in the middle could be a cell of its own. use the `numberOfItemsInSection:` function to define how many cells should be included in each section.

Comment: Thanks for @VS ) I Have edited your answer. I found that you can't set delegates as ID while you are using ARC

Comment: @Arthur, you can make above view using UICollectionView only, Thanks for editing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put following lines in your myCustomCell.h

```
@protocol ButtonTapDelegate

- (void) buttonDidTap:(UIButton*) button;

@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<ButtonTapDelegate> *vs_delegate;

-(void) buttonIsPressed;
```

in your myCustomCell.m

```
@synthesize vs_delegate;

-(void) buttonIsPressed:(UIButton*)button {

    if([delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ButtonTapDelegate)] && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonDidTap:)]) {
       [vs_delegate buttonDidTap:button];
    }
}
```

In your viewController.h

```
myViewController : UIViewController <ButtonTapDelegate>
```

In your viewController.m, inside Method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [cell set.Vs_delegate:self];
        [cell.button setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonIsPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.button buttonIsPressed:indexPath.row];
```

Put following method inside ViewController.m

```
- (void) buttonDidTap:(UIButton*) button {
 // You have index, by Button's tag.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient and clean way to do this using blocks.

Declare a **block property** in your cell either **TableViewCell** or **CollectionViewCell**.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^buttonClickedAtIndexPath)(NSIndexPath *indexPath);
```

Declare button's action in Cell itself and Call above block in button click event.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

  // get indexPath here, which will be indexPath of cell.
  // you need to set button's tag as indexPath.row

  if(self.buttonClickedAtIndexPath) {
    self.buttonClickedAtIndexPath (indexPath);
  }
}
```

In your ViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  TableViewCell *cell = // configure cell here.
  cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.buttonClickedAtIndexPath = ^(NSIndexPath *indexPath){

   // you can do anything here. 
   // Call any method using self OR
   // perform segue

  }

}
```

If you've CollectionView inside TableViewCell then same things applies.

- Make a class **MyCollectionViewCell** subclassing **UICollectionViewCell**.
- Declare block property in MyCollectionViewCell.
- Handle all the events in MyCollectionViewCell (including display data, delegate, datasource for collectionView).
- Call a block from MyCollectionViewCell on button click.
- Declare a property of **MyCollectionViewCell** in your **TableViewCell**.
- In your controller's **cellForRowAtIndexPath** do something like this.

============================================================

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  TableViewCell *cell = // configure cell here.
  cell.mycollectionView.buttonClickedAtIndexPath = ^(NSIndexPath *indexPath){

   // you can do anything here. 
   // Call any method using self OR
   // perform segue

  }

}
```